# line projection on top of a plane

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry, 3d

If I have a horizontal line (a 3d point and 3d vector with zero  z component) and another plane (could be an oblique or a horizontal; i have normal vector of the plane); then how do we get the direction (3d) of the 3d line which lie on top of the plane.

For that, I wish to project the above horizontal line on to the given plane.

(I made more clear the original post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what a 2d vector is.  I'm assuming you're specifying the line by the span of some vector $v$ translated by the 3d point $p$: $L = p + vt.$

You can specify a plane by two vectors and a point, or by a point and a vector.  For the first, call the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, and the point $q$.  The plane is $rv_1 + sv_2 + q$.

If $p + vt$ does not intersect the plane, the projection can be written as a translation.  If it does intersect the plane, pick $p$ and $q$ so that they coincide with the intersection of the line and the plane.  Change coordinates so that $p=q=0$.  Now all you do is project the vector $v$ onto $v_1$ and $v_2$.  The projection map is

$$tv\mapsto t\langle v,v_1\rangle v_1 + t\langle v,v_2\rangle v_2.$$

If you want to work with a point $q$ and a single vector $w$ which specifies the plane by $\{x\ |\ \langle x,w\rangle = 0\} + q$, again translate coordinates to the intersection point $p=q=0$.  Then project onto the span of $w$, and subtract that new line from the old line:

$$ vt\mapsto vt - t\langle v,w\rangle w. $$

Comment: I think that, with regards to the 2D vector, the OP is using the fact that the line is horizontal (i.e. it's really a 3D vector but with the third coordinate zero).

Comment: @Neal: sorry i didn't get you clearly. i know normal vector of the plane and the horizontal line (a point and direction of line). wouldn't it be taken by getting cross products of some vectors as i cannot get your previous explanation.

Comment: Yes, the a normal vector to a plane can be gotten by taking the cross product of two spanning vectors.

Comment: @lopsy That makes sense. I think of vectors and 1-forms as "1D", planes and 2-forms as "2D", and so forth, so referring to a vector by the dimension of its ambient space confused me.

Comment: @ Neal: No i want to know how can i get my required line (which lies on the plane) direction by getting the cross product of normal vectors? is it possible? if so, please tell me

Comment: You could take the cross product of the normal to the plane and a vector which is normal to the line and perpendicular to the plane normal.  But that will probably involve more computation than simply projecting.

Comment: @Neal: ok thanks